Film where an alien is found out by a question about when the Chicago Bears won the World Series
I am looking for a 1950s-60s alien invasion movie where the alien's local knowledge of earth is betrayed by a question from a sentry referring to how the Chicago Bears won the World Series last season.  The question obviously reveals the actual alien.  Anyone remember?

Because of course everyone knows that the Bears are, in fact, a hockey team.

@Valorum This kind of stuff was the way they detected Germans in bad World War II movies.

That question wouldn't just detect an alien. It would detect anyone who gives not two hoots about USAian sport, i.e. most of the rest of the planet.

If memory serves, David Niven was challenged by an American sentry to tell which team had won the World Series and he replied that he had "no bloody idea"
